# I can't authorize gmail api application in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-api, google-colaboratory, google-api-python-client, google-people-api

I'm running the quickstart code from https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python in a colab notebook.

```
# \[START people_quickstart\]

from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.

SCOPES = \['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'\]

def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the People API.
Prints the name of the first 10 connections.
"""
creds = None
\# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
\# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
\# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
\# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
creds.refresh(Request())
else:
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
'credentials.json', SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
\# Save the credentials for the next run
with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    
        # Call the People API
        print('List 10 connection names')
        results = service.people().connections().list(
            resourceName='people/me',
            pageSize=10,
            personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
        connections = results.get('connections', [])
    
        for person in connections:
            names = person.get('names', [])
            if names:
                name = names[0].get('displayName')
                print(name)
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()

# \[END people_quickstart\]
```

but it fails the authentication at this stage:

> http://localhost:52591/?state=K8nzFjxOrWJkPEqjeG1AZiGpsT5DSx&code=4/0ARtbsJoAH2rD9UYgHOKJ__UdJcq87d2vuFjEAqcI3aKJpj1rLJ-93TXR0_v-LnBR4Fytsg&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly

why is it redirected to localhost?
There is a simple way to send e-mail at google colab? with or without using gmail?

i'm using the google colab at opera browser.

Can anyone help me how i can send a simple e-mail at google colab without lowing the gmail security level?

T.T

Comment: This code has obvious syntax errors.  `SCOPES = \['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'\]` is an error due to the backslashes.  The `if` blocks have no indentation.  It's hard for us to help if we can't even run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

today I came across the same problem and the way I found to fix it was running the code in a Jupyter Notebook and then saving the token it was generated there and uploading it to colab.

I ran the code bellow and then a json file named 'token' was generated in the folder where my notebook is located:

```
import os.path

import google.auth.exceptions
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"]

creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    try:
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        creds.refresh(Request())
    except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
        # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
        creds = None
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials_web.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

When this is over just run the same code in colab and make sure you updated the token to the environment and thats it. Not simple, but it works

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the way you are loading the run_local_server if you are getting a 404 error.

The code below is my standard QuickStart for People api.  I just tested it and it works fine.  I am not getting a 404 error.

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib


from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

import google.auth.exceptions
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts']

def main():

    """Shows basic usage of the People API.
    Prints a list of user contacts.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        try:
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
            # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
            creds = None
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Call the People API
        print('List 10 connection names')
        results = service.people().connections().list(
            resourceName='people/me',
            pageSize=10,
            personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute()
        connections = results.get('connections', [])

        for person in connections:
            names = person.get('names', [])
            if names:
                name = names[0].get('displayName')
                print(name)
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You tested on google colab ambient? 

I copied your code excecute with my credentials but still don't work on colab.
Maybe i'm using the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs API in some wrong way...
I will try a diferent SMTP mail.